# iOS 4 AutoCorrects "me" to "^me"

Tags: iphone, ios, autocorrect

At one point, I typed "^me" into iOS 4. Now it corrects the word "me" to "^me" every time.   How can I remove this?

(I would like a solution to the problem. Pressing the X on the auto correct tooltip or disabling auto correct work, but they don't solve the problem.)

Answer (score 2):

Simply reset your Keyboard Dictionary.

As you type on iOS, it will begin to learn the words you use frequently. The frequently used words will take precedent after a while (most often seen with names). Sometimes this system makes a mistake and records a typo or a word that you'd rather not have iOS dish up.

To correct this matter, simply reset your Keyboard Dictionary. Tap **Settings > General**. Scroll down to the bottom and tap on **Reset**.

[image]

This will delete all the entries and restore your keyboard dictionary to its default state, removing the erroneous admission.

Answer (score 1):

Try making a note in Notes with the word "me" in it. Save the note. The contents of contacts and Notes (along with things like sent email and web searches) are said to be used to populate the autocorrection database.

Alternatively, you might want to do a search for "^me" on your phone and delete it, if it's saved anywhere.

See http://tntluoma.com/iphone/ducking-iphone/ and its comments for a discussion of this phenomenon.

Comment: I'm interested about where this behavior comes from.